# Cakephp: grant acl permission using cli

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to grant edit Users permission to a group (users) using the cli.

Here's the relevant line from the aros table:

```
id  parent_id   model   foreign_key     alias   lft     rght

3       NULL      Group     3              NULL     13      22
```

Here's the relevant line from from the acos table:

```
id  parent_id   model   foreign_key     alias   lft     rght
27      1          NULL     NULL            Users   68      89
31    27         NULL     NULL            edit    75       76
```

I tried using this command:

> cake acl grant users Users edit

but I got this error message:

PHP Warning:  DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node in /var/www/html/cakepf/cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php on line 361

Warning: DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node in /var/www/html/cakepf/cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php on line 361
Permission was not granted.

Any assistance on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake responds with an *invalid node* error: it cannot find the node you're referencing. When you look at the command you're executing, you're trying to access the node `users`. How should Cake know which node this is? The alias column for your node in your `aros` table is empty.

Solution: use the right alias in your `aros` table. You can also use `cake acl view aro` or `cake acl view aco` to see what your ACL tables look like to Cake.

Comment: So in order to use the acl cli commands, I have to first define aliases for everything? It's not possible to reference a node through,say, primary key?

Comment: I don't know, as I don't usually use the CLI to edit the ACL, but I found out you can also use the name that Cake gives to the node when you use `cake acl view aro`. In this specific case I believe that would be `Group.3`

Comment: Do you just insert directly into the aros_acos table?

Comment: I'm actually using [an ACL updating script from Mark Story](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/acl-extras-updated-to-cakephp-1-3) to automatically update my ACOs en AROs table (I use the AROs table only on groups, ie I don't use user-specific rights in my site).

Comment: Yes, ./Console/cake acl grant Group.1 controllers would be valid if you don't have an alias in the aros table